# multiple subordinate clauses in one sentence

Tags: grammar, english-to-german, subordinate-clause

I have difficulty translating this into German: *"The people who are crazy enough to believe that they can change the world, usually change the world"*

My problem lies with using "die" and "dass" in the same sentence, I don't know where to put "sind" now

> *die Menschen, **die** verrückt genug um zu glauben **sind**, **dass** sie die Welt verändern **können**, normalerweise verändern sie die
>   Welt*

oder

> *die Menschen, **die** verrückt genug **sind**, um zu glauben dass sie die Welt verändern können, normalerweise verändern sie die Welt*

Which translation is (more) correct?

Comment: The latter. Note that you've added a _sie_ in the main clause that isn't present in the original.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I agree with @Vogel612 that the "um"-clause is a bit clumsy; however, for the sake of completeness it should be mentioned that the correct form with "um" would be:

> Die Menschen, die verrückt genug sind, um zu glauben, dass sie die Welt verändern können, verändern für gewöhnlich die Welt.

So, you only missed the comma before *dass* and you applied a wrong order in the last part of the sentence. Other than that, your second translation is correct.

Answer (score 4):

In this case the latter sentence is the more correct one. I'd translate differently, though:

> *Die Menschen, die verrückt genug sind zu glauben, dass sie die Welt
>   verändern können, verändern normalerweise die Welt.*

This is a slight simplification over your sentence. You made it additionally difficult by introducing another subclause through "um".

Instead of repeating the "die Welt verändern" it is more idiomatic to shortcircuit by using "tun":

> *[...] die Welt verändern können, tun es normalerweise.*

Answer (score 1):

This is an instance in which German is actually logical.

> Die Menschen verändern normalerweise die Welt.

Welche *Menschen*?

> Die Menschen, die verrückt genug sind, verändern normalerweise die Welt.

In welchem Sinn *verrückt genug*?

> Die Menschen, die verrückt genug, um zu glauben, sind, verändern normalerweise die Welt.

Was *zu glauben*?

> Die Menschen, die verrückt genug, um zu glauben, dass sie die Welt verändern können, sind, verändern normalerweise die Welt.

Easy, right? However, it is not fashionable anymore to pile up verbs like “können, sind” (only two, it could get worse ;), so one would probably move “sind” to the front of the relative clause:

> Die Menschen, die verrückt genug sind, um zu glauben, dass sie die Welt verändern können, verändern normalerweise die Welt.